# How to use HMAC-SHA256 Authorization header with Unicode bytes instead of UTF-8?

Tags: paw-app

I'm creating HMAC-SHA256 Authorization header for my rest request.

My hunch is that internally Paw is using UTF-8 (or some other non-Unicode) encoding to calculate the checksum. My server side API uses Unicode to calculate the same thing for comparison but with the same inputs I receive different outputs on each end :(

Is there a way to configure Paw to use Unicode?

Answer (score 3):

For unicode inputs for HMAC-SHA256 you can use the Escape Sequence dynamic value. Choose ``Custom` escape sequence and type your sequence in the input field (\u + code for unicode characters and \x + code for hex bytes).

[image: sha256]

If this doesn't work for you, don't hesitate ti send us a support e-mail to support@luckymarmot.com

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will give it a shot